# Average method not working asp.net core code first:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-core, average

2 model classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CareCompProj.Models
{
public enum Profession { Counsellor, Physio, Doctor }
public class HealthProfessional
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptsMedicalCard { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> HealthReviews { get; set; }

    public double CalculateAverageRating()
    {
        var averageRating = HealthReviews.Average(r => r.Rating);


        return averageRating;
    }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CareCompProj.Models
{
public class Review
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ClientID { get; set; }
    public int? HealthProfessionalID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5, ErrorMessage = "Please select number between 1 and 5")]
    public int Rating { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string ReviewText { get; set; }
    public bool WouldRecommend { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public HealthProfessional HealthProfessional { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My 2 problems are

1. when I use the method created in the Healthprofessional class I get ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   Parameter name: source

e.g

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
<p> @item.CalculateAverageRating() </p>
}
```

2. if I use the ViewBag created in the Healthprofessional Index controller method. This returns Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[CareCompProj.Models.HealthProfessional, System.Double]]

When I go to the page URL where the rating should be.

Here is the ViewBag(created in the healthprofessional controller index method) I reference in the razor view when trying to get the average rating

```
 ViewBag.profRatings = _context.HealthProfessionals.Include(p => p.HealthReviews)

 ViewBag.profRatings = _context.HealthProfessionals.Include(p => p.HealthReviews)
                              .Select(x => new
                              {
                                  HealthProfessional = x,
                                  RatingAverage = x.HealthReviews.Any() ?
                                  x.HealthReviews.Average(v => (v.Rating)) : 0
                              });
```

The razor index view for health professionals uses

```
@model IEnumerable<CareCompProj.Models.HealthProfessional>
```

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are getting a `ArgumentNullException`, its because `HealthReviews` is `null` - make sure you populate it before you pass the model to the view (and do not use `ViewBag`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to materialize the result by calling `ToList()` in your controller action before setting in `ViewBag` or passing back from request using `return View(model)` so that the query is executed and result set is populated in the memory in the `List<T>`.

So for your linq query do:

```
var model = _context.HealthProfessionals.Include(p => p.HealthReviews)
                          .Select(x => new
                          {
                              HealthProfessional = x,
                              RatingAverage = x.HealthReviews.Any() ?
                              x.HealthReviews.Average(v => (v.Rating)) : 0
                          }).ToList();
```

Now either pass it back to view when returning like:

```
return View(model);
```

or you can set the `ViewBag.profRatings` and then use it in view.

### UPDATE:

you can create a ViewModel specific to your view requirements like:

```
public class HealthProfessionalVM
{

   public HealthProfessional HealthProfessional { get; set; }
   public int RatingAverage { get ;set; }
}
```

and then populate it in controller action instead of creating anonymous object:

```
var vm = _context.HealthProfessionals.Include(p => p.HealthReviews)
                          .Select(x => new HealthProfessionalVM
                          {
                              HealthProfessional = x,
                              RatingAverage = x.HealthReviews.Any() ?
                              x.HealthReviews.Average(v => (v.Rating)) : 0
                          }).ToList();

return View(vm);
```

and now strongly type your view to `IEnumerable<HealthProfessionalVM>` and iterate over it like:

```
@model IEnumerable<HealthProfessionalVM>

foreach(var item in Model) 
{ 
   <p> @item.RatingAverage </p>
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have applied this in my controller and assigned it to ViewBag.profRatings = model;

Next I called it in my index view using 
@foreach (var item in Model){
     <p> @ViewBag.profRatings </p>
}

Unfortunately I still get 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[CareCompProj.Models.HealthProfessional,System.Double]]
Where average number should be in my table. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to write: `foreach(var item in ViewBag.profRatings as IEnumerable<HealthProfessional>) { <p> @item.RatingAverage </p>`

Comment: States healthprofessional does not contain definition of RatingAverage if I do this within the razor view and Rating Average is underlined in red. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Instead of anonymous object you need a view Model class

Comment: I applied the latest update to your answer with some slight edits to match my project structure and it worked. I can't thank you enough :)